# Load a single large file from client to dask workers

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

How do I make a single large file of 8 GB accessible by all other worker nodes in dask? I have tried `pd.read_csv()` with `chunksize` and `client.scatter` but it is taking quite long. I am running it on macOS.

This is my code:

```
import time

import pandas as pd
import dask as dask
import dask.distributed as distributed
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.delayed as delayed
from dask.distributed import Client, progress


client = Client(IP:PORT)
print client
print client.scheduler_info()
f = []
chunksize = 10 ** 6

for chunk in pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize=chunksize):
    f_in = client.scatter(chunk)
    f.append(f_in)
print "read"

ddf = dd.from_delayed(f)        
ddf = ddf.groupby(['col1'])[['col2']].sum()

future = client.compute(ddf)
print future
progress(future)

result = client.gather(future)
print result
```

Stuck with it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Dask will chunk the file as long as it's a .csv file (not compressed), not sure why you are trying to chunk it yourself. Just do:

import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('data*.csv')

Comment: This wouldn't work, because the workers don't have access to the original data file.

Answer (score 0):

In your work-flow, you are loading the CSV data locally, parsing into dataframes, and then transmitting serialised versions of those dataframes to the workers, one at a time.

Some possible solutions:

- copy the file to each worker (which is wasteful in space terms), or put it in some location they can all see, like a shared file-system or cloud storage
- use [client.upload_file](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.upload_file), which wasn't really designed for a large payload, and would also replicate to every worker
- use `dask.bytes.read_bytes` to read the blocks of data in series as before, and persist those to the workers, so at least you suffer no serialisation cost, and the parsing effort is shared between the workers.

Comment: I am not sure if client.upload_file would take a csv file as input.